# How can I load value using localStorage which contain array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, local-storage

```js
$(function(){
 $('#subbtn').click(function() {
  var res = {};
  console.log($('#tab').find('tr'))
  $('tr').each(function(){
      var tmp = [];
      var cl ;
      $(this).find('select').each(function(){
        cl = $(this).attr('class');
        //console.log(cl);
        tmp.push($(this).val());
      })
      
      res[cl] = tmp
  })
 console.log(res);
   localStorage.setItem("testingvalue",JSON.stringify(res));
   document.getElementById("results__display").innerHTML = (localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));
 })
  
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="container centered">
<form class="content__form contact-form">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="bs-component" id="test1">
                        <table class="table table-responsive table-striped table-hover " id="tab">
                            <tbody>
        <tr class="info" id="alertr1">
                                    <td width="30px">1</td>
         <td width="200px">Likes Authority</td>
                                    <td  width="75px;">
          <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyL" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td  width="200px">Enthusiastic</td>
                                    <td  width="75px;"> 
          <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999;"
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyO" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td width="200px">Sensitive Feelings</td>
         <td width="75px;">
          <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyG" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td  width="180px">Likes Instructions</td>
         <td width="75px;">
          <select class="r1" style="position: absolute; z-index:9999; "
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyB" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="danger" id="alertr2">
                                    <td>2</td>
         <td>Takes Charge</td>
                                    <td>
          <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9998;"
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyL" >
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td>Takes Risks</td>
                                    <td>
          <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9998;"
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyO" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td>Loyal</td>
         <td>
          <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9998; "
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyG" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
         <td>Accurate</td>
         <td>
          <select class="r2" style="position: absolute; z-index:9998; "
           onmouseover="this.size=this.options.length"
           onmouseout="this.size=1" onchange="this.size=1"  name="qtyB" > 
           <option value="0">-</option>
           <option value="1" >1</option>
           <option value="2" >2</option>
           <option value="3" >3</option>
           <option value="4" >4</option>
          </select>
         </td>
                                </tr>
                                
                                </tbody>
                        </table>
                        <div id="source-button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" style="display: none;">&lt; &gt;</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<button class="contact-form__button" id="subbtn" type="button" >Send it</button> 
</form>
<div class="results">
  <h2 class="results__heading">Form Data</h2>
  <pre class="results__display-wrapper"><code id="results__display"></code></pre>
</div>

</body>
```

Currenly, I had a form and some class name which is from r1 to r10. And in one row, I had 4 select option.The row was until r10. Now I got a jquery function which is read the each row content and store into a array. How can I call these array into specific row and column? 
For example if I choose r1 for 2,3,1,4 then user leave the current page then he come back again and request to view their previous input. The select option in r1 will automatic fill with 2,3,1,4. Thanks.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or a code snippet on here?

Comment: Yes, Please wait a while.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Updated already. Please take a look, thanks.

Comment: You are assigning an array as value for the innerHTML, you should generate HTML based on that information and display that. I can give an example when I am home.

Comment: @Knerd Yes, ermm, I don't care whether I was assign in innerHTML or a console, I just want to get the store value and assign it independently into the correct row and column.

Comment: @Knerd thats fine... ( .toString() is called)

Comment: @Beginner may use JSON.parse and Array.prototype.forEach...

Comment: @Jonasw But when I use JSON.parse, I don't know why it return `[object] [object] `but if I didn't put it, it can show the array.

Comment: @Beginner: and then you need to iterate... You cannot put an object into your html...

Answer (score 2):

As `LocalStorage` only supports strings, you go the correct way with `JSON.stringify(res));`. Now if you want to access that data again you should do something like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   var jsonData = {};
   try { 
      jsonData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("testingvalue"));
   } catch (error){
       console.log('could not load data from storage');
   }

   // access your data
   for(var klass in jsonData){
      var index = 0;
      $(klass).find("select").each(function(){
        // todo probably check if index exists
        $(this).val(jsonData[index]);
        index++;
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: yes! I also don't know how to do the onload, I am just a beginner,thanks ! But I get a syntax error **Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

Comment: please see the update of my answere, $(document).ready(function(){}); is the way to go if you are using jquery. Was my bad concerning the syntax error, I did not execute the code. just added the closing brackets in line 5.

Comment: Thanks,but this didn't work for me :( Thanks anyway.

Comment: Note that you should put that code at the end of the body. Also check your data array and adjust the access and iteration of the data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your `var res = {};` should be global else each time you click btn value will reset

Assuming your res variable is global and you know attr name here c1

```
var tmp = res[cl];
tmp[0] => will give you first value 
tmp[1]
tmp[2]
tmp[3]
```

Note: Pls add null checks accordingly

Comment: That's means I had to declare it outside the function?

Comment: Yes. it has to be global and should not get affected by any event

Comment: Nope. It can be local, however its not really a good style. And i dont know what your answer should show us...

Comment: @Jonasw  As per example var was defined inside click event which is not accessible outside click event so I suggested to define it outside click